# GORM db.First print log automatically

Tags: go-gorm

I am using the latest [GORM v2](https://gorm.io/).

When I use `db.First(&AoiArea{})`, it triggers a record not found error output in the log if nothing is found.

```
    if err := db.First(&AoiArea{}).Error; errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Automatic O/P from `First`:

> 2021/09/17 09:02:24 ←[31;1mE:/xyz-api/models/utils.go:47
> ←[35;1mrecord not found ←[0m←[33m[0.000ms] ←[34;1m[rows:0]←[0m SELECT * FROM "aoi_area" ORDER BY "aoi_area"."id" LIMIT 1

Is there any way to prevent this default log?

I see there is a similar question here https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html#comment-5083714457 in their documentation Q&A but no appropriate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `First` will always print the error log.

> If you want to avoid the `ErrRecordNotFound` error, you could use `Find` like `db.Limit(1).Find(&user)`, the `Find` method accepts both struct and slice data

doc is here: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

You can try this

```
db.Limit(1).Find(&AoiArea{})
```